# tf.argmax with equality in tensorflow doesn't give me the expected result

Tags: tensorflow

Can anyone tell me why the below line give me False. Knowing I am using tensorflow 2.0

```
tf.argmax(input= tf.constant([0., 1, 0.]) == tf.argmax(input=tf.constant([0., 1, 0.])
False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the equality. I should use `tf.equal` with tensors.

Answer (score 0):

First, `tf.constant([0., 1, 0.])` will produce a vector of [ 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0 ].

Next, `tf.argmax(input=tf.constant([0., 1, 0.])` will produce a integer ( since you are using `argmax` with `axis=0`, which will be 1. The item at index 1 in the vector has the highest value.

You are trying to compare,

[ 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0 ] and 1

Which, in any case, are not equal. Hence the output was False.

Comment: But I am producing the 1 index in both sides of equal.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, that you work with tensors before evaluation, not with values. So, always use special tensorflow functions, like `tf.equal()` in this case.